# Acumatica: How do I change a warning to an error?

Tags: acumatica

Issue:
We would like to change a warning message to an error message on the Sales Order Entry screen SO301000.  The warning in particular we want to change is when the Line Item Quantity will take the Available Quantity negative.  Currently it is a yellow warning message, but we would like it to be a Red Error.

[Current Warning Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTRif.jpg)

I am a programmer, but new to Acumatica.  I have been through the courses but this particular situation is not covered.

I was hoping for just a point in the right direction to get started.  I will take it from there.  Appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Ext_SOOrderEntry : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public void SOLine_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e, PXRowUpdated del)
    {
        del?.Invoke(sender, e);
        if (e.Row == null)
            return;

        const string targetWarning = "quantity available will go negative";

        string warning = PXUIFieldAttribute.GetWarning<SOLine.orderQty>(sender, e.Row);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(warning)
            && warning.Contains(targetWarning))
        {sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<SOLine.orderQty>(e.Row,
                                                               ((SOLine)e.Row).OrderQty,
                                                               new PXSetPropertyException(warning,
                                                                                          PXErrorLevel.Error));
        }
    }
    public void SOLine_Availability_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e, PXFieldSelecting del)
    {
        del?.Invoke(sender, e);
        if (e.Row == null)
            return;

        const string targetWarning = "quantity available will go negative";

        string warning = PXUIFieldAttribute.GetWarning<SOLine.orderQty>(sender, e.Row);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(warning)
            && warning.Contains(targetWarning))
        {
            sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<SOLine.orderQty>(e.Row,
                                                               ((SOLine)e.Row).OrderQty,
                                                               new PXSetPropertyException(warning,
                                                                                          PXErrorLevel.Error));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Diego - Thank you. This worked perfectly!   
Appreciate the help and insight Diego and Hugues!

Answer (score 1):

Try using method `PXUIFieldAttribute.GetWarning` to obtain the warning message. And then use `PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError` to set the error.

Example:

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public void SOLine_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        const string targetWarning = "Target Warning Message";

        string warning = PXUIFieldAttribute.GetWarning<SOLine.orderQty>(sender, e.Row);

        if (warning?.Contains(targetWarning) == true)
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<SOLine.orderQty>(sender, e.Row, warning);
        else
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<SOLine.orderQty>(sender, e.Row, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also suggest to run base method first adding a delegate as third parameter
check this gist: https://gist.github.com/diperez/75ec67307ab8251e5d2e9245d3ad53be

Comment: When you omit declaring base I'm pretty sure it calls base first then it calls the graph extension event handler. Otherwise most customization would brake the system. I usually declare it only when I need base method to be called after the extension method.

Comment: Hugues.  Thank you.  I see and understand.   Where do I go to insert this?    Would that be in Customizations >> CODE,  or in VS?  (Sorry for the newbie Acu question)

Comment: Hugues, you can ignore my previous question.  I was able to add the code and publish.  But there was no change in the Line Item - it still has the warning.   Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Check @diegoapereza answer, I tested it, it works. The main issue is that this particular warning is not set using RowSelected (which is most common case)